# modifying a code to print our coordinates

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have this simple code, that draws a perfect hexagon, and I would to modify it to print out and locate the x,y coordinates of each node, Any one can help me please in doing that?

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *

#Encapsulation
def polygon(t, n=6, length=100):
    angle = 360.0/n
    for i in range(n):
        fd(t, length)
        lt(t, angle)
world = TurtleWorld()
bob= Turtle()
print bob
polygon (bob)
polygon(bob, 8, 70)
wait_for_user()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the turtle's position via the `.get_x()` and `.get_y()` methods ([Docs](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/TurtleWorld.html#Turtle)).  For example, changing your for loop to:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(t.get_x(), t.get_y())  # <---
    fd(t, length)
    lt(t, angle)
```

Outputs

```
(0, 0)
(100.0, 0.0)
(150.0, 86.60254037844386)
...
```

And for completeness, here's your full code, refactored to remove the wild import and cleaned up a bit:

```
import swampy.TurtleWorld as tw

#Encapsulation
def polygon(t, n=6, length=100):
    angle = 360.0/n
    for _ in range(n):
        print(t.get_x(), t.get_y())
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)

world = tw.TurtleWorld()
bob = tw.Turtle()

polygon(bob)
polygon(bob, 8, 70)

tw.wait_for_user()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for your great help , thank you.

I just would like to ask please if its possible to ask for your help, in trying to display the x,y coordinates in a simple GUI using Tkinter, Can you help me please cause I'm totally new to python, and I need to display these coordinates in an x,y sort of GUI. thats it

many thanks again